# Merging two objects based on key value

Tags: php

I have two objects from an API I am trying to merge, one is a list of available subscription packages and one is a list of the current user's active subscription's and the corresponding status.

The first object looks like this:

```
This\Collection Object
(
    [object] => list
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 444
                    [name] => Test Plan 4
                )

            [1] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 333
                    [name] => Test Plan 3
                )

            [2] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 222
                    [name] => Test Plan 2
                )

            [3] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 111
                    [name] => Test Plan 1
                )

        )

    [has_more] => 
)
```

This second object looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This\Subscription Object
        (
            [id] => sub_xxx
            [current_period_end] => 1670307654
            [current_period_start] => 1667715654
            
            [plan] => This\Plan Object
                (
                    [currency] => usd
                    [product] => 111
                )

            [start_date] => 1667715654
            [status] => active
        )

    [1] => This\Subscription Object
        (
            [id] => sub_xxx
            [current_period_end] => 1770507654
            [current_period_start] => 1767715454
            
            [plan] => This\Plan Object
                (
                    [currency] => usd
                    [product] => 333
                )

            [start_date] => 1767715654
            [status] => active
        )

)
```

I want to combine the second object with the first object if `subscription->plan->product` matches `product->id` so it would look something like this:

```
This\Collection Object
(
    [object] => list
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 444
                    [name] => Test Plan 4
                )

            [1] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 333
                    [name] => Test Plan 3
                    [subscription] => This\Subscription Object
                    (
                        [id] => sub_xxx
                        [current_period_end] => 1770507654
                        [current_period_start] => 1767715454
                        
                        [plan] => This\Plan Object
                            (
                                [currency] => usd
                                [product] => 333
                            )

                        [start_date] => 1767715654
                        [status] => active
                    )
                )

            [2] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 222
                    [name] => Test Plan 2
                )

            [3] => This\Product Object
                (
                    [id] => 111
                    [name] => Test Plan 1

                    [subscription] => This\Subscription Object
                    (
                        [id] => sub_xxx
                        [current_period_end] => 1670307654
                        [current_period_start] => 1667715654
                        
                        [plan] => This\Plan Object
                            (
                                [currency] => usd
                                [product] => 111
                            )

                        [start_date] => 1667715654
                        [status] => active
                    )

                )

        )

    [has_more] => 
)
```

I know I can perform two foreach loops on each object and turn them into arrays with the revenant data I need and combine them that way, but I would rather merge them complete as objects.

How can I merge/combine these two in PHP?

Edit: This was my attempt at merging the two, but I am lost on how to actually make it work:

```
foreach($array1 as $product) {
    foreach($array2 as $subscription) {
        if ($subscription->plan->product == $product->id){
            //how do I append to the object in the right place (where the 0 is)?
            $array1->data[0]->subscription = $subscription->plan;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if this is Laravel then you could achieve the same using relationships. :)

Comment: You can use two foreach loops to achieve this as you said. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @OMiShah - it's not.

Comment: @nice_dev - I only know how to do that if you turn them both into arrays first. Could you show me without doing that?

Comment: @tony, you can call ``->toArray()`` on the collection to cast to array and then you can loop through the array and check.

Comment: Ok, can you share the var_export of your inputs?

Comment: @nice_dev - I updated my code to show you my attempt. I don't know if having a nested foreach loop is a good idea though.

Comment: @tony Snippet here should work for you https://pastecode.io/s/rnmt6pgh

Comment: Doh! got it. If you want to post that as an answer I will mark it correct. Stupid oversight on my part.